# For embedded code, why should I use "uint_t" types instead of "unsigned int"?

Tags: c, embedded, gcc

I am writing an application in c for an STM32F105, using gcc.

In the past (with simpler projects), I have always defined variables as `char`, `int`, `unsigned int`, and so on.

I see that it is common to use the types defined in stdint.h, such as `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `uint32_t`, etc.  This it true in multiple API's that I am using, and also in the ARM CMSIS library from ST.

I believe that I understand why we should do so; to allow the compiler to better optimize memory space.  I expect there may be additional reasons.

However, because of c's integer promotion rules, I keep running up against conversion warnings any time I try to add two values, do a bitwise operation, etc.  The warning reads something like `conversion to 'uint16_t' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]`.  The issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12941878/3380131) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18629780/3380131).

It doesn't happen when using variables declared as `int` or `unsigned int`.

To give a couple of examples, given this:

```
uint16_t value16;
uint8_t value8;
```

I would have to change this:

```
value16 <<= 8;
value8 += 2;
```

to this:

```
value16 = (uint16_t)(value16 << 8);
value8 = (uint8_t)(value8 + 2);
```

It's ugly, but I can do it if necessary.  Here are my questions:

1. Is there a case where the conversion from **unsigned** to **signed** and back to **unsigned** will make the result incorrect?
2. Are there any other big reasons for/against using the stdint.h integer types?

Based on the answers I'm receiving, it looks like the stdint.h types are generally preferred, even though c converts `uint` to `int` and back.  This leads to a bigger question:

3. I can prevent the compiler warnings by using typecasting (e.g. `value16 = (uint16_t)(value16 << 8);`).  Am I just hiding the problem?  Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Use unsigned literals: i.e. `8u` and `2u`.

Comment: Thanks, @OrangeDog, I think I'm misunderstanding.  I tried both `value8 += 2u;` and `value8 = value8 + 2u;`, but I get the same warnings.

Comment: Use them anyway, to avoid signed warnings when you don't already have width warnings :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A standards-conforming compiler where `int` was anywhere from 17 to 32 bits may legitimately do *anything it wants* with the following code:

```
uint16_t x = 46341;
uint32_t y = x*x; // temp result is signed int, which can't hold 2147488281
```

An implementation that wanted to do so could legitimately generate a program that would do nothing except output the string "Fred" repeatedly on every port pin using every imaginable protocol.  The probability of a program getting ported to an implementation which would do such a thing is exceptionally low, but it is theoretically possible.  If want wanted to write the above code so that it would be guaranteed not to engage in Undefined Behavior, it would be necessary write the latter expression as `(uint32_t)x*x` or `1u*x*x`.  On a compiler where `int` is between 17 and 31 bits, the latter expression would lop off the upper bits, but would not engage in Undefined Behavior.

I think the gcc warnings are probably trying to suggest that the code as written is not completely 100% portable.  There are times when code really should be written to avoid behaviors which would be Undefined on some implementations, but in many other cases one should simply figure that the code is unlikely to get used on implementations which would do overly annoying things.

Note that using types like `int` and `short` may eliminate some warnings and fix some problems, but would likely create others.  The interaction between types like `uint16_t` and C's integer-promotion rules are icky, but such types are still probably better than any alternative.

Comment: Just to be clear: `uint32_t y = (uint32_t)x*x` is what one "should" write here, to standards-objectively express the intuitively-intended outcome of the technically "undefined" code?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: If `x` is known to be `uint16_t` and/or hold a value less than `sqrt(INT_MAX)`, that would work, but a conforming implementation could have a `short type` with 31 value bits, one sign bit, and no padding, `unsigned short` with 32 value bits and no padding, and `signed int` with 32 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 7 padding bits.  On such an implementation, `uint32_t` would be a synonym for `unsigned short`, and so multiplying two `uint32_t` values, or even incrementing a `uint32_t` value that was equal to 0xFFFFFFFF could yield Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: When the Standard was written, I would suspect such an implementation would have been seen less implausible than one which targets a common quiet-wraparound 32-bit two's-complement platform but would process `unsigned y = x*x;` nonsensically for `x` greater than 46340.

Comment: A `uint32_t` **is** capable of losslessly storing the product of two `uint16_t`s. At least, 0x0000\*0x0000=0x00000000, and, at most, 0xFFFF\*0xFFFF=0xFFFE0001. If **a "naive" developer** writes the product of two `uint16_t`s to be captured as a `uint32_t`, I don't see _any_ ambiguity about the _intent_…but how is _that_ intent **supposed to** be expressed, to "make" a conformant compiler enact it?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: If an implementation processes in Standard-defined fashion at least one (possibly contrived and useless) program that exercises the translation limits listed in the Standard, nothing it does with any other source text could render it non-conforming; it's impossible to "make" a conforming implementation do anything.  That being said, `1u*x*y` would be the safest way of ensuring that the product of `x` and `y` will be processed with the larger of `x` or `y`'s type if bigger than `unsigned`, or `unsigned` otherwise.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: A lot of problems could have been avoided if the Standard had made clear that in situations where parts of the Standard and an implementation describe a behavior, but some other part of the Standard says it's undefined, the Standard waives jurisdiction *to let implementations specify behavior as tightly or loosely as would best serve their customers*.

Comment: I am definitely aware of the fact that the Standard is _a bit odd_ around the edges...mainly I was just wondering, _given_ the current state of it, what the "correct" way to multiply/add/etc. packed ints/uints into a container I _know_ is big enough to hold them (or that a mod/trunc would be appropriate for overflow). Is there any reason to choose a 1/1U premultiply **instead of** a precast?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: Casting to the destination container type should work if one isn't interested in mod-reducing the result.  If one were performing a hash computation that required multiplying two 32-bit numbers to yield the bottom 32 bits of the result, casting to `uint32_t` might not cause prevent the computation from being promoted to e.g. a 64-bit signed `int`.  As for the Standard being "odd around the edges", there would be nothing odd about it if compiler writers recognized and honored its intended purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Since Eugene's #2 is probably the most important point, I just would like to add that it's an advisory in

```
MISRA (directive 4.6): "typedefs that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic types".
```

Also Jack Ganssle appears to be a supporter of that rule: http://www.ganssle.com/tem/tem265.html

Comment: It's too bad there aren't any types for specify "N-bit unsigned integer which may be safely multiplied by any other same-size integer to yield the same sized result".  Integer promotion rules interact horribly with the existing types like `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 6):

1) If you just cast from unsigned to signed integer of the same length back and forth, without any operations in between, you will get the same result every time, so no problem here. But various logical and arithmetical operations are acting differently on signed and unsigned operands.
2) The main reason to use `stdint.h` types is that the bit size of such a types are defined and equal across all of the platforms, which is not true for `int`, `long` e.t.c., as well as `char` has no standard signess, it can be signed or unsigned by default.  It makes easier to manipulate the data knowing the exact size without using extra checking and assumptions.

Comment: The sizes of `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are equal across all platform **on which they are defined**. If the processor doesn't have an **exactly matching** hardware type, these types are not defined. Hence the advantage of `int` etc. and, perhaps, `int_least32_t` etc.

Comment: @PeteBecker - That's arguably an advantage, though, because the resulting compile errors make you immediately aware of the problem.  I'd much rather that than my types changing size on me.

Comment: @sapi - in many situations the underlying size is irrelevant; C programmers got along just fine without fixed sizes for many years.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Part of the reason programmers got by without "officially" fixed-sized types is that it was commonplace for implementations to treat each type other than `int` and `unsigned int` as the smallest type with the required range.  While "short" and "long" weren't officially specified as 16-bit and 32-bit types, there was no perceived reason for implementations targeting octet-based platforms to treat them as anything else.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to eliminate the warnings is to avoid using -Wconversion in GCC. I think you have to enable this option manually, but if not, you can use -Wno-conversion to disable it. You can enable warnings for sign and FP precision conversions via [other options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), if you still want those.

The -Wconversion warnings are almost always false positives, which is probably why not even -Wextra enables it by default. A [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c) has a lot of suggestions for good option sets. Based on my own experience, this is a good place to start:

> -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow

Add more if you need them, but odds are you won't.

If you must keep -Wconversion, you can shorten your code a bit by only typecasting the numeric operand:

```
value16 <<= (uint16_t)8;
value8 += (uint8_t)2;
```

That's not easy to read without syntax highlighting, though.

Answer (score 2):

in any software project, it is very important to use portable type definitions. (even the next version of the same compiler needs this consideration.  )  A good example,  several years ago I worked a project where the current compiler defined 'int' as 8bits.  The next version of the compiler defined 'int' as 16bits.  Since we had not used any portable definitions for 'int', the ram (effectively) doubled in size and many code sequences that depended on a 8bit int failed.  The use of a portable type definition would have avoided that (hundreds of man hours to fix) problem.

Comment: No reasonable code should use `int` to refer to an 8 bit type.  Even if a non-C compiler like CCS does so, reasonable code should use either `char` or a typedefed type for 8 bits, and a typedefed type (not "long") for 16 bits.  On the other hand, porting code from something like CCS to a real compiler is apt to be problematic even if it uses proper typedefs, since such compilers are often "unusual" in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. An n-bit signed integer can represent roughly half the number of non-negative numbers as an n-bit unsigned integer, and relying on overflow characteristics is undefined behavior so anything can happen. The vast majority of current and past processors use twos complement so a lot of operations happen to do the same thing on signed and unsigned integral types, but even then not all operations will produce bit-wise identical results. You're really asking for extra trouble later on when you can't figure out why your code isn't working as intended.
2. While **int** and **unsigned** have implementation defined sizes, these are often chosen "smartly" by the implementation either for size or speed reasons. I generally stick to these unless I have a good reason for doing otherwise. Likewise, when considering whether to use int or unsigned I generally prefer int unless I have a good reason to do so otherwise.

In cases where I really need better control over the size or signed-ness of a type, I usually will prefer either using a system-defined typedef (size_t, intmax_t, etc.) or make my own typedef which indicates the function of a given type (prng_int, adc_int, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Often the code is used on ARM thumb and AVR (and x86, powerPC and other architectures), and **16 or 32 bit can be more efficient** (both ways: flash and cycles) **on STM32 ARM even for a variable that fits in 8 bits (8 bit is more efficient on AVR)**. However if SRAM is almost full, reverting to 8 bit for global vars can be reasonable (but not for local vars).
For portability and maintenance (especially for 8 bit vars), it has advantages (without any disadvantages) to **specify the MINIMUM suitable size**, instead of the exact size and typedef at one .h place (usually under ifdef) to tune (possibly uint_fast8_t / uint_least8_t) during porting / build time, eg:

```
// apparently uint16_t is just as efficient as 32 bit on STM32, but 8 bit is punished (with more flash and cycles)
typedef uint16_t uintG8_t; // 8bit if SRAM is scarce (use fol global vars that fit in 8 bit)
typedef uint16_t uintL8_t; // 8bit on AVR (local var, 16 or 32 bit is more efficient on STM + less flash)
// might better reserve 32 bits on some arch, STM32 seems efficient with 16 bits:
typedef uint16_t uintG16_t; // 16bit if SRAM is scarce (use fol global vars that fit in 16 bit)
typedef uint16_t uintL16_t; // 16bit on AVR (local var, 16 or 32 bit whichever is more efficient on other arch)
```

[GNU library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integers.html) helps a bit, but normally the typedefs make sense anyway:

```
typedef uint_least8_t uintG8_t;
typedef uint_fast8_t uintL8_t;
```

// but uint_fast8_t for BOTH when SRAM is not a concern.